# Rails: require_tree is not serving my stylesheets and javascripts

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

So I just cloned a repository, and all works fine. The database migrated well, and bundle ran well too. But I can't get the style sheets in `app/assets/stylesheets/` to be served in development, as well with the javascript. The site uses bootstrap so it's fairly important. I'm currently working in development mode, and I see that application.css/js is served to the browser by looking at the page source, but no other files are.

The following is the content of both application files:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */

body {
    padding-top: 40px;
}

.alert {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was solved by bumping the rails version in the Gemfile to 3.2.13. Don't know why that was the case, and why it didn't work as cloned. That's what fixed it though.